# How to put a Divider between DropdownMenu items in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, material-ui, drop-down-menu, material-design

[image: This is what I want to achieve]I have a **DropdownMenu** and I want to draw a horizontal divider(line) between **DropDownMenuEntries**.

'dropdownMenuEntries' property only expects a List of DropDownMenuEntry Widgets.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: if you can attach a UI sample. It will more understandable your expectation.

Comment: @TanvirulIslam attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the same Dropdown menu using [dropdownbutton2](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2).
Below is the code for ourCustomDropdown:

```
class OurCustomDropdown extends StatelessWidget {
  final Controller c;
  final List<String> dropdownItems;
  final String dropdownValue;
  final void Function(String?)? onChanged;

  const OurCustomDropdown({
    super.key,
    required this.c,
    required this.dropdownItems,
    required this.dropdownValue,
    required this.onChanged,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child: DropdownButton2<String>(
        isExpanded: true,
        items: dropdownItems
            .map((String item) => DropdownItem<String>(
                  value: item,
                  height: 20.0,
                  child: Text(
                    item,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ))
            .toList(),
        value: dropdownValue,
        onChanged: onChanged,
        buttonStyleData: ButtonStyleData(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
            border: Border.all(
              color: kSelectedCardColor,
            ),
            color: kSelectedCardColor,
          ),
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        dropdownStyleData: kDropdownStyleData,
        dropdownSeparator: const DropdownSeparator(
          child: Divider(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selectedItemBuilder property from the DropDownMenu

```
selectedItemBuilder: (context) => widget.listOfDropDownContent
          .map(
            (text) => Column(children: [
                                Text(text), 
                                Divider(),
                              ])
          )
          .toList(),
```

Comment: DropDownMenu Widget doesn't have 'selectedItemBuilder' property.

Answer (score 0):

@bbr Following my recommendation, you should generate a custom `DropdownMenuItem` view, as demonstrated in the provided code. Please review it, as I believe it will be beneficial to you!

```
DropdownButton(
            isExpanded: true,
            isDense: true,
            value: dropdownvalue,
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.arrow_drop_down,
              color: Colors.brown,
            ),
            iconSize: 40,
            onChanged: (String? val) => setState(() => dropdownvalue = val!),
            items: items.map((option) {
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                value: option,
                child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8.0, 0, 6.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border(
                            top: BorderSide(color:  items.indexOf(option) == 0
                                    ? Colors.transparent
                                    : Colors.grey, width: 1))),
                    child: Text(option)),
              );
            }).toList(),
            selectedItemBuilder: (con) {
              return items.map((item) {
                return Text(item);
              }).toList();
            }),
```

Comment: Actually, I'm using the 'DropdownMenu' (Material 3) Widget not 'DropdownButton'.(In fact, DropdownButton has been officially updated to DropdownMenu). (Kindly, check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html).